# Why does running kate in ubuntu hardy give me errors?

Tags: ubuntu, console, kde

Running kate on the command line in ubuntu hardy works but prints a bunch of junk to the screen like:
kbuildsycoca running...

it's really annoying.  anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I know the workaround to redirect standard error, which is fine.  Guess I was curious why there were errors.

Comment: I continue to get answers to this question telling me what standard error is for.  Let me clarify, I understand the purpose of error logging.  I wanted to know whether there was something I should do to fix the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not really supposed to be run from the command line.  You can redirect the junk to `/dev/null`, though:

```
kate >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But that doesn't "fix" it, as such, just make the junk invisible.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe the messages are standard, and that kde apps are usually only launched from the command-line by developers.

Answer (score 0):

Run it from its menu entry or from the Ctrl+F2 "Run dialog box"

Answer (score 0):

Could you not make an alias to the command suggested by womble?

for example

```
alias mykate='kate >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

then every time you run mykate in the terminal you should not see any of the messages

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answers here this is a feature, not a bug to be fixed.

If kate were ever to stop functioning correctly you could use the information provided on the console to help the developers figure out what's wrong and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite normal.  All (or most) gui apps print logs of what they do, so if they crash, you can usually find out why from the logs.

Pretty useful actually

Answer (score 0):

The messages are debug information that can be useful when troubleshooting a bug. In that case you can start the application from command line and log all the messages generated and include it in your bug report.

As previously noted, if you start the application from the desktop you will not see any of those messages. You can also suppress them by redirecting them to /dev/null if you need to start your application for the commandline.